# How to reduce the frequency of the "RPC method invocations" arose as a result of ethers.js event listener?

Tags: javascript, events, ethers.js, hardhat

By running an "event listener" (and nothing else) through [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-on); alike:

```
contract.on("Transfer", (to, amount, from) => {
    // ...
});
```

the Hardhat node console keeps logging some specific RPC methods, like, for ever:

```
eth_chainId
eth_blockNumber
eth_chainId (2)
eth_getLogs (2)
eth_chainId
eth_blockNumber
eth_chainId (2)
eth_getLogs (2)
eth_blockNumber
eth_chainId (2)
eth_blockNumber
...
```

I believe ethers.js continuously queries the blockchain-logs for events (presumably in a predefined time-interval, or whatever). I need to to decrease the frequency of the "RPC method invocations" down (through increasing the aforementioned hypothetical time-interval, or whatever). So, How may I achieve that?

Comment: are these really coming from hardhat? the logs you've provided there look like the hooks for useBlockNumber, and a few other hooks,  are you sure they're spawn from your event listener.  because TBH those look like very similar to the ones in uniswap ui

Comment: @johnny5 Yes, of course; to confirm that, I've removed the event listener and there was nothing on the console (re-enabling the event listener, gets the logs back.)

Comment: weird, maybe you're not using the right endpoint, are you using the websockets one?

Answer (score 0):

Without much context I would suggest using a websocket-provider.

That said, a few things to consider if that is not an option:

- You can get rid of the `eth_chainId` calls by using `StaticJsonRpcProvider` instead of e.g. `JsonRpcProvider`.
- You can then try setting the `provider.pollingInterval` to a higher value. Important thing to consider with this is that to my knowledge the poller only gets logs for the 10 most recent blocks. So if `pollingInterval` is higher than block time * 10, it will miss blocks (and the events) built after the previous poll.